# In Asp.net MVC , Ajax Auto Postback failed to work properly,while using Ajax.beginform in Partial View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

To **display some-text in a Display-Box**,when user **changes** values in a **Dropdownlist**.For this purpose i used **PartialView**, **Ajax.BeginForm** and **Jquery.change function**.

**Issue** : In the main-**View* i am using **@html.Beginform()** and **@Ajax.BeginForm** is used in **partial view**, so while i changes the value in Dropdownlist, **Jquery Form submit** is calling **@html.Beginform()** in main-View other than **@Ajax.BeginForm**

Expected Behavior:**Jquery Form submit** should call **@Ajax.BeginForm** in partial View

```
//following Scripts are included in View, Partial-View
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

**In Main View**

```
    @model Shopping.Models.Mob
//Issue:This "Html.BeginForm" is called during submitting from partial View 
    @using (Html.BeginForm("MobileSell", "MobileSell", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <table>
      <tr><td>**@Html.Partial("_SelectedMobileList", Model)**</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr><td><div id="NextFields">**@Html.Partial("_SelectedMobileDetails", Model)**</div></td>
      </tr> 
    </table>
    }
```

**In _SelectedMobileList Partial-View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FillMobileDetails", "MobileSell", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod ="POST", 
                                                              UpdateTargetId ="NextFields",
                                                              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
{
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MobileName, Model.MobileList, "select one", new { id="Drop1"})</td>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(fun1)

    function fun1()
    {   alert("test1");   $("#Drop1").change(fun2);   }

    function fun2()
    {alert("test2");   

    //Jquery function calling submit-form
    //Expected to invoke "Ajax.BeginForm" but invoking "html.BeginForm"
     $(this).parents('form').submit();

    }
 </script>
```

**In _SelectedMobileDetails Partial-View,which need to display test**

```
@model Shopping.Models.Mob
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.MobileEmi)
```

**In Controller**

```
//Issue: Invoking this action-method.
public ActionResult MobileSell()
{
ObjectResult<SP_Fetch_Mobile_Details_Result> objResult = objContext.SP_Fetch_Mobile_Details();
SelectList objSelectList = new SelectList(objResult.ToList(), "MobileName", "MobileName");
objMobile.MobileList = objSelectList;
return View(objMobile);
}

[HttpPost]
//Excepted: To invoke this Action Method 
public PartialViewResult FillMobileDetails(Mob Model)
{
Response.Write("test3");
Model=new Mob();
Model.MobileEmi="somEmi";
return PartialView("_SelectedMobileDetails",Model);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use simple $.ajax call, not ajax form, just as a workaround. Your action than wil return json with details(not view), parse and fetch it where you need.

Comment: @Den Thanks,since i am new in ajax ,please help me to  convert the following to simple ajax call    `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FillMobileDetails", "MobileSell", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod ="POST", UpdateTargetId ="NextFields", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like :

```
function fun2() {
     var mobile= $('#MobileName option:selected').text();
            var data = {mobileName: mobile  };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FillMobileDetails","MobileSell")',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'

            }).done(ShowDetailsSucc).fail(ShowDetailsFail);
        }

       function ShowDetailsSucc(data) {

           //fetch fields via jquery
           //$("#DetailField1").html(data.emi);
           //............
        }
        function ShowDetailsFail() {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
```

And your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult FillMobileDetails(string mobileName)
{
Response.Write("test3");
Model=new Mob();
Model.MobileEmi="somEmi";
//get emi and else if need
return Json(new {emi=Model.MobileEmi,detail1="something"});
}
```

Comment: kindly check this link , i had done simlar thing here but getting same problem. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238523/in-asp-net-mvc-how-to-change-the-value-of-textbox-in-a-partial-view-using-autop