# In asp.net MVC, How to change the value of TextBox in a Partial View using AutoPostBacking

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to Auto Postbacking in MVC Asp.net.
i need to **change the value of textbox2**, While **Auto postbacking the Partial View** and Autopostback should happen only **after a click in textbox1**

Issue: textbox2 is not changing the value after autopostbacking.

Further findings: Post Success Function is working("function SetData(data)")  ,     so when i debugged the code, it AutoPostBacked to ActionMethod:"Test()" and executed the code and returned to _PartialViewTwo and executed code dere , but it did not changed the TextBox2 value

note: TextBox1 is in PartialViewOne ,TextBox2 is in PartialViewTwo

Thanks in advance for any help.

// GET: Home

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Response.Write("working Index");
    Student Model = new Student();
    Model.RollNo = 1;
    Model.Name = "Arun";
    return View(Model);
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Test()
{
    Student Model = new Student();
    Response.Write("working test3");
    Model.Name = "Afsal";  
    return PartialView("_PartialViewTwo",Model) ;
}
```

**Home View**

```
@model test1.Models.Student
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Post))
    {
     <table>
      <tr> <td>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.RollNo) 
           <td>@Html.Partial("_PartialViewOne",Model)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><div id="divpartialview">@Html.Partial("_PartialViewTwo",Model)</div></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    }
```

**PartialViewOne**

```
    @Html.TextBox("txt1")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(fun1)
    function fun1()
    {
        alert("ready");
        $("#txt1").click(fun2);
    }
    function fun2()
    { 
        alert("click");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Test/Home")',
            data: null,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                SetData(data);
            }
        });
    }
    function SetData(data) {
        alert("again");
        $("#divPartialView").html(data); // HTML DOM replace
    }
    </script>
```

**PartialViewtwo**

```
@model test1.Models.Student
  @Model.Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@To all : Issue is fixed. its a case sensitive error in  the  selector "**$("#divPartialView")**.html(data)" inside the jquery function  "function **SetData(data)**" , now it is changed to"**$("#divpartialview ")**"  ........ **....:P**

```
function SetData(data) {
        alert("again");
        $("#divpartialview ").html(data); // HTML DOM replace
    }
```